# Issues after taking the integral by using Dirac delta: a jump of the integrand

Tags: integration, special-functions, dirac-delta

**Introduction**

Consider the integral
$$
\tag 1 I= \int f(x,t)\ g(y)\ \delta(m(x,y,t,a,b)) \ dx\ dy\ dt ,
$$
where

- $a,b$ are positive parameters, and $b>a$,
- The integration ranges for $x,y,t$ are correspondingly $x\in [a,y_{\text{max}}]$, $y\in [0,y_{\text{max}}]$, $t\in [-1,1]$,
- $f(x,t)$, $g(y)$ are non-negative functions for all $t$, $x \geqslant a$, $0\leqslant y \leqslant y_{\text{max}}$, and being zero for $x<a$, $y<0$
- $g(0) = g_{0}>0$,
- $m(x,y,t,a,b)=a^{2}+b^{2} - 2\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\sqrt{y^{2}+b^{2}}+2xy t$

I evaluate the integral $(1)$ by using the identity
$$
\delta(m(x,y,t,a,b)) = \sum_{i = 1,2}\frac{\delta(y-y_{i})}{|m'|_{y_{i}}},
$$
where $y_{i} \equiv y_{i}(x,t,a,b)$ are solutions of $m(x,y,t,a,b) = 0$. Therefore the integral takes the form
$$
\tag 2 I = \int f(x,t)\left[\sum_{i = 1,2}  \frac{g(y_{i})}{|m'|_{y_{i}}}\right]dx\ dt \equiv \int \mathcal{I}(x,t)\ dx \ dt
$$

**Question**

One of $y_{i}$s is always positive (if real), while another one is negative for $x \in (a, x_{\text{crit}}(a,b))$, where $x_{\text{crit}}(a,b) = \frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{2b}$, and becomes positive for $x \geqslant x_{\text{crit}}$, continuously passing through 0.

Since $g(y<0) = 0$ and $g(0) =g_{0}\neq 0$, the integrand in $(2)$ experiences a jump 
$$
\Delta = \mathcal{I}(x_{\text{crit}}+0,t)-\mathcal{I}(x_{\text{crit}}-0,t) = f(x_{\text{crit}},t)\frac{g(0)}{|m'|_{0}}
$$
This jump probably says to me that I made a mistake somewhere between $(1)$ and $(2)$. However, I don't understand where exactly.

Could you please tell me where I did it, and how to correct $(2)$ for getting correct estimation?

Comment: What are the integration ranges for $x, y, t$? Consider that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x^2 + y^2 - 1) f(y) dy$ is the sum that you wrote out if $|x| < 1$ but is zero if $|x| > 1$.

Comment: @Maxim : The integration ranges for $x,y,t$ are correspondingly $[a,y_{\text{max}}]$, $[0,y_{\text{max}}]$, $[-1,1]$. I have updated the question by adding this information.

Comment: Seems fairly difficult. You need to compute the bounds for the part of the surface $m = 0$ that lies inside the volume you're integrating over. Whichever variable you start with, it seems unwieldy without some additional assumptions. You may try to do it with a CAS, if it's capable of computing a cylindrical decomposition of $m = 0 \land (x, y, t) \in V$.

Comment: @Maxim : of course, after evaluation of the integral over y, I established that t changes in limits
$$
t \in [t_{\min}, 1],
$$
where $t_{\text{min}} = -1$ if $x < x_{\text{crit}}$ and $t_{\text{min}} = \frac{1}{2b}\frac{\sqrt{4x^{2}b^{2}-b^{4}-2a^{2}b^{2}-a^{4}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$ otherwise. For these values, $y_{i}$s are always real, one of them is always positive, and another one is positive for $x \geqslant x_{\text{crit}}$. The integral over $x$ I then take numerically.

Comment: @Maxim : just to be clear, first I take the integral over $y$ by using delta-function analytically, second I find the sub-region for $t$ for which $m = 0$ (the limits from the comment above), and then I simply insert them into Wolfram Mathematica. In my case it is not sensitive to limits for $x$ (I mean that it automatically evaluates them).

Comment: I'm worrying only about the special point $y = 0$. Please take a look on a P.S. part of my question.

Comment: Also, not sure how helpful this is, but a jump doesn't necessarily mean something is wrong. Taking a simple example again, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x^2 + y^2 - 1) dy = [-1 < x < 1]/\sqrt {1 - x^2}$. The result is not continuous in $x$.